# Hint for Number Theory question.

Tags: number-theory, order-theory, primitive-roots

I need a hint for this question please: Find the sum of the orders mod 83 over all elements of the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,82\}$. (If multiple elements have the same order, add that term multiple times.)

I figured out that all numbers except $1$ (has order $1$) and $82$ (has order $2$) must have orders of $41$ or $82$. But how do I know how many numbers with orders of $41$ or $82$ there are?

Comment: Every element of order $82$ is a primitive root and the amount of primitive roots $\mod n$ is equal to $\phi(\phi(n))$.

Comment: Where does this fact come from?

Comment: the group of all numbers coprime to $n$ under multiplication $\mod n$ has order $\phi(n)$ and is cyclic. The amount of generators of a cyclic group of order $m$ is equal to $\phi(m)$. Hence the amount of generators of the group of numbers coprime to $83$ under multiplication $\mod 83$ is $\phi(\phi(83))$.

Comment: Suppose $g$ has $82.$  $g^2$ has order $41, g^n$ has order $\frac {82}{\gcd (82,n)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

83 is prime, so the multiplicative group is equivalent to the cyclic group with $\phi(83)=82$ elements. In a cyclic group of order $n$, there are $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$ (where $d$ must divide $n$). So the answer is $\sum_{d|n}d\phi(d)$. I'm not sure if there's a closed expression for this, but with $n=82$, I get 4923.

Comment: You can use multiplicativity to turn this sum into $\prod_{p^k||n}(p^{k+1}-p+1)$, but this isn't much of a simplification.